# slideShow com tempo diferente ao aumentar quantidade de imagens

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho o `jQuery` abaixo que está funcionando muito bem.

Exceto por um detalhe: A `lógica` do for não está correta:

A `ideia` é que o `tempo de transição` entre **uma `imagem` e outra** seja o mesmo independente da **quantidade** de `imagens`. Mas, da forma que está, quanto mais imagens, mais rápido cada uma passa.

Como corrigir isso?

Onde estou errando na `lógica`?

Esse `snippet` está melhor visualizado no `Firefox`!

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {

  var tempoTransicao = 20;
  var quantasImagens = $("div.slider ul.slide li img").size();
  var tamanhoIntervalos = 100/quantasImagens;
  var tempoImagens = 0;
  var t = 0; 
  var tMax = 0; 
  
  var obj = new Array();
  
  for (i = 0; i < quantasImagens; i++) {
  
 tMin = tMax;
 tMax += tamanhoIntervalos;
  
 obj[tMin + '%'] = { 'margin-left': '-' + tempoImagens + '%'};
 obj[tMax + '%'] = { 'margin-left': '-' + tempoImagens + '%'};
 
 tempoImagens += 100;
 
  }   
  
  console.log(obj);

  $.keyframe.define([
  $.extend(
    { name: 'tocaSlide' }, 
    obj
    )
  ]);
  
  $("div.slider ul.slide").css({
  'animation-duration' : tempoTransicao + 's',
  });
  
});
```

```css
  * {   
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   boder: none;
  }
  body {
   width:1000px;
   margin: auto;
  }
  div.slider {
   width:100%;
   overflow:hidden;
  }
  div.slider ul.slide {
   width:5000%;
   animation:tocaSlide infinite;
  }  
  div.slider ul.slide li {
   width:100%;
   list-style:none;
  }
  div.slider ul.slide li img {
   float:left;
  }
  @keyframes tocaSlide {}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='http://www.hotplateprensas.com.br/estilos/_js/jquery.keyframes.min.js'></script>

  <div class="slider">
    <ul class="slide">
      <li><img src="http://www.hotplateprensas.com.br/estilos/_imgs/_slideShow/1.png" /></li>
      <li><img src="http://www.hotplateprensas.com.br/estilos/_imgs/_slideShow/2.png" /></li>
      <li><img src="http://www.hotplateprensas.com.br/estilos/_imgs/_slideShow/3.png" /></li>
      <li><img src="http://www.hotplateprensas.com.br/estilos/_imgs/_slideShow/4.png" /></li>
      <li><img src="http://www.hotplateprensas.com.br/estilos/_imgs/_slideShow/1.png" /></li>
      <li><img src="http://www.hotplateprensas.com.br/estilos/_imgs/_slideShow/2.png" /></li>
      <li><img src="http://www.hotplateprensas.com.br/estilos/_imgs/_slideShow/3.png" /></li>
      <li><img src="http://www.hotplateprensas.com.br/estilos/_imgs/_slideShow/4.png" /></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: Você está incrementando, por isso é mais rapido, basta definir uma variavel global com o tempo e utiliza-la, ao inves de ficar incrementando no `for`

Comment: Não consegui entender muito bem. Poderia, por favor, postar uma resposta explicando melhor? Pelo que seri, se eu não incrementar, todas as imagens estariam todas sobrepostas